# How should I handle thread updates to an internal Dictionary, possibly after thread.delegate exits?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, threadpool

I have N threads that are each saving data to a `private Dictionary<string,myObject> myUploadObject` variable with instance-object scope.

Once there is sufficient data in that dictionary, or after 2 minutes pass, I'll upload that collection to the server.

I've never encountered this multi-threaded situation and not sure how to approach this. Here is how I'm launching my initial code:

```
        PerfmonClient agent = new PerfmonClient(Machine, Start, Stop, Interval, MaxIterations);
        Thread newThread = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Creating new thread: " + agent.ToThreadName());
        ThreadStart threadDelegate = new ThreadStart(agent.TestLoop);
        newThread = new Thread(threadDelegate);
        agent.AssociatedThread = newThread;
        AgentDictionary.Add(agent.ToThreadName(), agent);
        newThread.Start();
```

Now I'm trying to get data out of within the `agent` object and send it to the server.  I would normally just call another method within the instance of `PerfmonClient` to do so, but the threading concept is making me double check my approach.

Here are some ways I'm considering taking that collected data and sending it to the server:

- Create a new ThreadDelegate for the `agent.upload` method, load it and run it (Main thread, or spawned thread)
- Change the internal object `Dictionary<string,myObject> myUploadObject` to public and static, and use a threadDelegate/Main thread to do the upload.
- ?? Not sure what happens if the initial `agent.TestLoop` exits, or errors out?  Do I loose all the data within the `agent` object?  How do I access internal data it when `thread.IsActive == false?`

Thank you for answering these questions... or pointing me in the right direction.  I'm not sure if I'm re-inventing the wheel here and may need to learn something new.

Comment: it's not quite clear to me what your overall design goal is with this, also if you're on .NET 4 and expect multiple threads accessing the Dictionary, consider ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: Design goal: Spawn some threads to do work, have that work saved somewhere (anywhere) in memory.  Upload that to a server using WCF in a controlled way as to not flood the receiver or sender.

Comment: I'm .NET 3.5 and using a dedicated Object() for locking read/write access to the internal Dictionary.  Thanks for the tip, I'll make a note of it

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a Dictionary? Can different threads update the same keys?

Comment: @The Scrum Meister I'm using a dictionary just because it's relevant to the runtime operations (expansion)  and also it needs a Key Value pair. Are you aware of an issue relating to me choosing that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a central uploader thread that provides a method `AddPerformanceData` to add performance data that the collection threads can call. This method uses a lock and stores the data internally. The uploader thread then sends that data in order using the lock for access as well.

This has the advantage that you don't need any locks on the collection threads since no-one else is accessing their data - you basically serialize the upload through the uploader thread.

Comment: How would I get all my CollectData threads to use the same uploader method (in a new class I suppose)?

Comment: Seconds Broken glass, and I would use some of the synchronization primitives that .Net provides like WaitHandle and call the method of WaitAll. When all threads complete their work, You can upload things to the server. You would need to store the threads somewhere though.

Comment: The threads run forever, until stopped.  I need to coalesce and upload the data either on timer tick, when x items are queued, or when thread exits.